# How to show xcconfig product name in infoplist.String?

Tags: swift, localization, info-plist, xcconfig

I have multiple target like development , AdHoc and production and also have respective XCConfig too. Now we need to integrate localisation in our application so i have added infoplist.string file for permission localisation but now $(PRODUCT_NAME) key no longer print application name. Any help will be great.

```
NSCameraUsageDescription = "$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses camera for capture image;
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8971488/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for quick replay i will look into this

Comment: Not working @MartinR

Comment: @ChiragShah Did you found the solution. I am struggling with the same.

Comment: No @PriyankaWadherMistry I did not find any solution for same